# Does length contraction occur in all 3 dimensions?

Tags: special-relativity

In special relativity length contraction occurs in the direction of travel for an object.

However, since physics is a science of observations, has it ever been observed not to simultaneously occur in the object's other two dimensions or is it just always assumed not to occur?

If it doesn't occur, why not?

Comment: Related though not quite a duplicate: [Prove no contraction in the orthogonal directions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399281/9887)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine two vertical toothpicks, each with a little light at its top and bottom, passing each other in the horizontal direction.  Each toothpick can tell whether its top and bottom lights pass over or under the other toothpick, or whether they hit the other toothpick and are reflected back.

Therefore the toothpicks are able to agree on which one is shorter.

But if there were a relativistic length contraction, each would say the other is shorter than itself, contradicting that agreement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123298/discussion-between-silverrahul-and-python-house).

Answer (score 1):

> However, since physics is a science of observations, has it ever been observed not to simultaneously occur in the object's other two dimensions or is it just always assumed not to occur?

The Michelson Morley experiment (MMX) was originally explained as due to length contraction by Lorentz. This was prior to Einstein’s development of special relativity, but the experiment can still be understood as evidence for length contraction. However, the MMX is not compatible with length contraction in all three directions.

Answer (score 1):

Another thought experiment that might help you to see the contradiction if objects contracted along directions perpendicular to their motion.

Imagine 2 identical hollow cylinders moving towards each other along their axis.
Now, if objects contracted along the perpendicular directions,

then according to the frame of cylinder A, cylinder B will have a smaller radius and hence cylinder B will pass inside cylinder A.

But according to the frame of cylinder B, cylinder A will have a smaller radius and hence cylinder A will pass inside cylinder B.

But, these two cannot both be true. You cannot have both A passing through B and B passing through A.
This contradiction hopefully shows you why it is not possible that objects contract along the directions perpendicular to their direction of motion

Comment: It is not related to OP arguments just my own curiosity. If we would have a solid foamy body expanding at great speed, what would be the description? I see that direction of motion is radial for every speck. But whatever happen along this radial directions should affect the spherical volume. I hope is clear...

Comment: Since, each speck is moving in a radial direction, each of these specks would be length contracted in the direction of motion of that speck. If this affects the spherical volume, then it affects the spherical volume.

Comment: Thanks. Right, the funny point is that we'll have something contracting while expanding. I thought It is curious, isn't it?